# want to replace cwm recovery with twrp on lenovo k3 note

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, twrp, lenovo

I want to replace cwm recovery with the twrp recovery on my lenovo k3 note. Can anyone share the step by step procedure to do this?

Comment: How did you flash CWM at first place?

Comment: using fastboot & adb when i was rooting my device. Got a post on xda-developers forum.

Comment: Why not follow the same procedure?

Comment: actually i am new to android and this whole rooting/modding business. I will try the same procedure and come back here if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have flashed CWM to TWRP by using a App called "Rashr". You should make your K3-Note root condition because Rashr needed root permission and put your unzipped TWRP image file into SD card open Rashr flash recovery image directly! It is a easy way to change recovery from CWM to TWRP.

Answer (score 0):

- Download and install ADB
- Download your K3 Note Recovery https://mega.nz/#F!RwEHyDYA!afI2c2A_hI8jHJ9MvjPauw <-
  here
- connect your phone in fastboot mode
- Check for your phone with cmd in administrator mode

  **1. fastboot devices**
- If yes then flash your recovery

  **2. fastboot flash recovery 'filename.img'**

Ta-Da your CWM recovery will be replaced with TWRP

**note: sometimes you need to replace "recovery" in the second command with "boot"**

I had the above problem with my Sony Xperia M2 dual Did this and replaced my CWM recovery With TWRP 3.x